# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

This issue with superadminController all other controller it is working fine.And also this issue in the live server localhost everything is working fine. I m using laravel 6.17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case it was a matter of Linux's file name case sensitivity.
Your file name is App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController and your class is superadminController.
you can change your class name to SuperAdminController. it will be fixed

Comment: Thanks sok. hai. you saved my time. its case issue in linux thank you so much

Comment: If this answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer. This could help others.